# .offset function inside .scroll function not works in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the top of '#select' element when scrolling. I have following codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($('#select').offset().top);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="select"></div>
```

But the thing it prints is not fixed during scrolling and I think it is the value of $(window).scrollTop(). when I put 'console.log ...' outside of '$(window)....' function everything works fine. What is the problem?

I found now the problem is from selector. In some cases when I changed the id it works fine, but for the 'select' id it not works and all the time it prints $(window).scrollTop() . Any one can help in this case? (Perhaps there is some problem with the css of '#select' element)

Comment: Syntax error, missing just about everything !

Comment: And it seems to be fixed for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/8tj34c4w/

Comment: @adeneo, I fixed the coding errors in the OP's question (based on your feedback) and the snippet is now running as expected, ;-)

Comment: @Marventus - Please do not edit the code of a question. See, [How far can I refactor the code in someone else's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question) and [When is it appropriate to edit someone else's code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code)

Comment: Ooops!! It was an typing error here. My real code is the code you are thinking but the problem is not solved.

Comment: I found now the problem is from selector. I edited the post.

Comment: @Reza - The code you have posted is still broken. You have `$(document).ready(){` where you should have `$(document.ready(function(){`.  If this is a typo, please edit your question to correct it.

Comment: @gilly3: No I don't think so. It is the jQuery syntax. I am pretty sure.

Comment: lol.  Open your JavaScript console and click the "Run code snippet" button. You'll see ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0SrQ.png).  Or just count the parentheses in your code. You have 8 open parentheses and 9 close parentheses.

Comment: I am sorry you are right. I am so sorry for a lot of typing issues. My real code is free of these issues. Do you have any idea for my problem? (I have no syntax error in my code)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing some brackets...

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($('#select').offset().top);
  });
});
```